# how to make a .desktop file pointing to "the newest file in a specific folder"?

Tags: nautilus, launcher, .desktop, shortcuts

I create .desktop files to launch the files I am working on (eg. the stories I am writing and editing, etc.)
Whenever I finish a story and I start working on a new one, I need to replace the shortcut with a new one (actually I need to open the .desktop file and replace the file path in "Exec=..." with the new one manually.)
Is there any command or option I can use in "exec=" line of .desktop file which points to the newest file in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some scripting inside the `Exec` line.

Something like shown below:

```
Exec=sh -c "xdg-open $(ls -t1 ~/your-dir/* | head -n1)"
```

Notes:

1. The `sh -c` is used to allow nested command execution
2. The `xdg-open` is used to open file using default application
3. The `ls -t1 ~/your-dir/*` lists all files by in the `~/your-dir` directory (change to correct path) by time and place them in single column
4. The `head -n1` extracts first item from `ls`'s output by using piping with `|`

Comment: I used to use your answer to solve my problem and it did work very well. recently it does not. and I found that if I change the names of the files to english it works. but it did work with unicode names (like داستان in persian) before.